# Apollo Gateway not working inside docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, graphql, microservices, apollo-server

I am trying to setup a simple Federated Apollo Gateway using Docker and docker-compose but can't seem to get the gateway to connect to the schemas services.

Here is the `docker-compose.yml` file

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  gateway:
    build: ./api-gateway
    ports:
      - 4000:8080
    depends_on:
      - robots
      - sitemaps
    environment:
      APOLLO_KEY: ${APOLLO_KEY}
    volumes:
      - ../secrets/credentials.json:/tmp/key/credentials.json
      - ./api-gateway/index.js:/usr/src/app/index.js
  
  robots:
    build: ./api-robots
    ports:
      - 4001:8080
    environment:
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: /tmp/key/credentials.json
    volumes:
      - ../secrets/credentials.json:/tmp/key/credentials.json
      - ./api-robots/src:/usr/src/app/src


  sitemaps:
    build: ./api-sitemaps
    ports:
      - 4002:8080
    environment:
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: /tmp/key/credentials.json
    volumes:
      - ../secrets/credentials.json:/tmp/key/credentials.json
      - ./api-sitemaps/src:/usr/src/app/src
```

In the gateway code I am registering the `robots` and `sitemaps` services using the following:

```js
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server");
const { ApolloGateway } = require("@apollo/gateway");

// Initialize an ApolloGateway instance and pass it an array of
// the implementing service names and URLs
const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
  serviceList: [
    { name: "robots", url: "http://robots:4001" },
    { name: "sitemaps", url: "http://sitemaps:4002" },
  ],
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
  gateway,
  subscriptions: false,
});

server
  .listen(8080)
  .then(({ url }) => {
    console.log(` Gateway Server ready at ${url}`);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Failed to start Gateway");
  });
```

Yet, when it runs, I get the following error reported by the gateway service:

```
gateway_1   | Error checking for changes to service definitions: Couldn't load service definitions for "robots" at http://robots:4001: request to http://robots:4001/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.3:4001
gateway_1   | This data graph is missing a valid configuration. Couldn't load service definitions for "robots" at http://robots:4001: request to http://robots:4001/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.3:4001
```

I know that the services are working correctly because I am able to connect to the `robots` and `sitemaps` services from the host at `http://localhost:4001` and `http://localhost:4002` respectively; and both work without any issues.

I've read countless threads about this and the most common issue that I find is that others are incorrectly trying to connect on `localhost` instead of using the services name (e.g. `robots` and `sitemaps`) as the domain name.  I am not making that mistake.

Here are some other things I have tried, but also did not work ...

- creating a custom `networks` definition and assigning it to each service
- connecting to `http://robots:8080` and `http://sitemaps:8080`
- connecting to `http://localhost:4001` and `http://localhost:4002`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hmm, probably networks will be the best option ... AFAIR related to some firewall settings ... log into gateway and check ping to services ... probably address resolved properly (you can try `extra_hosts` if not), then try curl some requests ... no `/graphql` endpoints (url) required on services ?

Comment: If the processes inside the containers are listening on port 8080, you need to use that port number in the URLs.  `ports:` aren't considered (or required) when making connections between containers.

Comment: ra9r, are you on mac? If you can connect via `http://localhost:4001`, why are you trying to connect via `http://robots:4001`? Another thought - you lack [container names](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#container_name) in your docker-compose.yaml. So the real hostname (container name) wouldn't be `robots`, but some random name like `folder_robots_1` (checkable with `docker ps`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be requesting to port 8080 instead of 4001, that's all. It should be `http://robots:8080` and `http://sitemaps:8080`